# Gravity forms – create single product field dynamically

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to create new fields (single products) for my form dynamically from a custom post type. That works quite well in the frontend. Now, one issue with this is that, once form is submitted, all the fields EXCEPT these dynamically added ones are in the submission. The other issue is, that also the total field (as for calculation needs) ignores the dynamically created ones.

I guess it has to do with the hooks. But every hook I tried, doesn't change a thing.

```
add_filter( 'gform_form_post_get_meta_1', 'populate_beers');

function populate_beers($form) {

                    $new_field_id = 0;
                        foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
                            if( $field->id > $new_field_id ) {
                                $new_field_id = $field->id;
                            }
                        }

                    $new_field_id++;
            $beers = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=bier' );
                    //var_dump($beers);

                    foreach ( $beers as $beer ) {
                                  // Prepare field properties
                            $props = array(
                                'id'        => $new_field_id,
                                'type'      => 'singleproduct',
                                'label'     => $beer->post_title,
                                'basePrice' => floatval( $beer->preis ),
                                'enableCalculation' => true
                            );
                                    //var_dump($props);

                            // Create new gravity forms field and add it to the form object
                            $nf = GF_Fields::create( $props );

                            // Hack - insert into array at specific position
                            // Needed to display product fields before other fields
                            // in the form
                            array_splice( $form['fields'], 5, 0, array($nf) );

                            $new_field_id++;
                        }

        return $form;
}
```

I've also tried these hooks already:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_process_1', 'populate_beers' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_beers' );
```

Here's the output of the logging regarding the saving problem for clarification:

```
2021-01-26 8:40:48.944197 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Starting to process form (#1) submission. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.944871 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Source page number: 1. Target page number: 0. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.945425 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): After validation. Is submission valid? Yes. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.945449 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Submission is valid. Moving forward. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.945477 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): Saving entry. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948657 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): Entry record created in the database. ID: 16. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948826 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): Saving entry fields. 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948880 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Name(#1.2 - name). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948913 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Name(#1.3 - name). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948936 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Name(#1.4 - name). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948961 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Name(#1.6 - name). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.948983 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Name(#1.8 - name). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949018 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Anschrift(#2.1 - address). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949042 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Anschrift(#2.2 - address). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949067 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Anschrift(#2.3 - address). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949090 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Anschrift(#2.4 - address). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949114 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Anschrift(#2.5 - address). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949136 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Anschrift(#2.6 - address). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949172 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Telefon(#3 - phone). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949207 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: E-Mail(#13 - email). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949239 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Collaboration Pale Ale(#18 - product). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949271 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: What is Love?(#17 - product). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949301 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Exploring New Galaxies(#16 - product). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949331 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Devil in Disguise(#15 - product). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949362 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Gooseberry Gose(#14 - product). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.949409 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Versand(#7 - shipping). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.953788 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::queue_save_input_value(): Queued field operation: Summe(#5 - total). 
2021-01-26 8:40:48.957503 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::save_entry(): Finished saving entry fields.
```

{all_fields} and {pricing_fields} didn't show those product fields, the totals and the shipping field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define the required `inputType` in your properties.

The correct way to define a dynamic product in gravityforms is to declare it as a `type => product`, define an `inputType` like `singleproduct` and don´t forget to add the `inputs` array to the properties if you are using `singleproduct` as `inputType`.

**Example:**

```
$props = array(
    'id' => $new_field_id,
    'type' => 'product',
    'inputType' => 'singleproduct',
    'label' => $beer->post_title,
    'basePrice' => floatval( $beer->preis ),
    'enableCalculation' => true,
    'inputs' => array(
        array(
            'id'    => $new_field_id.'.1',
            'label' => $beer->post_title,
            'name'  => 'param_product'
        ),
        array(
            'id'    => $new_field_id.'.2',
            'label' => 'Price',
            'name'  => 'param_price'
        ),
        array(
            'id'    => $new_field_id.'.3',
            'label' => 'Quantity',
            'name'  => 'param_qty'
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Available inputTypes for a gravityforms product are:**

- singleproduct
- select
- radio
- price
- hiddenproduct
- calculation

Also try to add a dynamic totals calculation to your form like this:

```
$calculation = GF_Fields::create(array(
    'id' => 1000,
    'label' => 'Totals',
    'type' => 'total',
));
array_push( $form['fields'], $calculation );
```

Your Gravityforms Hook should work:

```
add_filter( 'gform_form_post_get_meta_1', 'populate_beers' );
```

Comment: That fixes the totals calculation problem, thank you! But the problem that once the form is submitted, all the fields EXCEPT these dynamically added ones are, haven't been resolved. Surprisingly also totals calculations and shipping fields aren't saved. Do you have any hint what hook/action/filter that would be? Currently checked with {all_fields}.

Comment: Hi @Bernard i updated the answer above. If you declare a `singleproduct` you also have to define the `inputs` array in the properties. If you set them correctly the entries should be saved in the backend. Make shure you use the `gform_form_post_get_meta` Hook. If the validation of the form is incorrect, the dynamic fields are always empty. I think you have to create an extra function hooked to the `gform_validation` or `gform_field_validation` Hook to validate your custom fields. [link](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/).

Comment: Hi Rjanits, the missing inputs array was causing the problem – I didn't see the wood for the trees. Yeah! Now i owe you a beer ;)